# How to create N-level treeview or recursion logic for comment system in android?

Tags: java, android, data-structures, treeview, expandablelistview

I am currently stuck with a problem that when I started out seemed not to hard to solve for me, but i am stuck for a couple of hours now, so here we go:

I am creating a comment system for a forum application, My comments data for particular post is **JSON** format which look like this

```
[
   {
      "ID":16,
      "TopicID":4,
      "ParentID":14,
      "Text":"Some Comment text",
      "Likes":0,
      "DisLikes":0,
      "SubComments":[
         {
            "ID":22,
            "TopicID":4,
            "ParentID":16,
            "Text":"Some Comment text",
            "Likes":0,
            "DisLikes":0,
            "SubComments":[
               {
                  "ID":23,
                  "TopicID":4,
                  "ParentID":22,
                  "Text":"Some Comment text",
                  "Likes":0,
                  "DisLikes":0,
                  "SubComments":[ N level ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }, N level
]
```

My POJO for this json data is Comment.java and which have getters and setters, In that SubComment is `List<Comment> SubComments = new ArrayList<Comment>();`

I am using this https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView lib to create treeview, using this lib I created three level view but I want to create for N-level.

Code so far I tried is creating 3 level

```java
public void success(Comment[] comments, Response response) {

                ViewGroup containerView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
                TreeNode root = TreeNode.root();

                for (Comment comment : comments) {
                    TreeNode level_one = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(comment.getBy().getUserName(), comment.getCommentedAt(), comment.getText(), ""+comment.getLikes(), ""+comment.getDisLikes(), comment.getBy().getInitials(), comment.getBy().getColorCode(), comment.getBy().getProfilePicture(), comment.getBy().isIsDefaultPicture())).setViewHolder(new IconTreeItemHolder(getApplicationContext()));
                    for (SubComments subComments : comment.getSubComments()) {
                        TreeNode level_two = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(subComments.getBy().getUserName(), subComments.getCommentedAt(),subComments.getText(), ""+subComments.getLikes(), ""+subComments.getDisLikes(), subComments.getBy().getInitials(), subComments.getBy().getColorCode(), subComments.getBy().getProfilePicture(), subComments.getBy().isIsDefaultPicture())).setViewHolder(new IconTreeItemHolder(getApplicationContext()));
                        for (Comment comment1 : subComments.getSubComments()) {
                            TreeNode level_three = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(comment1.getBy().getUserName(), comment1.getCommentedAt(),comment1.getText(), ""+comment1.getLikes(), ""+comment1.getDisLikes(), comment1.getBy().getInitials(), comment1.getBy().getColorCode(), comment1.getBy().getProfilePicture(), comment1.getBy().isIsDefaultPicture())).setViewHolder(new IconTreeItemHolder(getApplicationContext()));
                            level_two.addChildren(level_three);
                        }
                        level_one.addChild(level_two);
                    }
                    root.addChild(level_one);
                }

                AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(getApplicationContext(), root);
                tView.setDefaultAnimation(true);
                tView.setDefaultViewHolder(IconTreeItemHolder.class);
                tView.setDefaultContainerStyle(R.style.TreeNodeStyleCustom);
                containerView.addView(tView.getView());

            }
```

Now, What I am looking for is

1. How to create n-level tree structure using recursion or without using recusion?
2. How to access a nested object like

   ```
     main_comment_1_obj
        -> sub_comment_1.1_obj
           -> sub_comment_1.1.1_obj
              -> sub_comment_1.1.1.1_obj  
        -> sub_comment_1.2_obj
           -> sub_comment_1.2.1_obj
           -> sub_comment_1.2.2_obj
     main_comment_2_obj
        -> N-level
   ```
3. Should I have to try a different way?

Comment: @DerGol...lum I have tried NLevelExpandableListView  it satisfies my first need that is creating n-level tree structure but i am unable to access nested list objects as i mentioned in my second need, so could you tell me any solutions for that?

Comment: @DerGol...lum I have gone through source code of NLevelExpandableListView, in that static string +i parameter values passed to NLevelItem, In my case values are in subcomments(nested objects) how to access nested list obj to get child values? , this is where i stuck!